# Disabling Flutter Hero reverse animation

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, flutter

Given 2 routes, e.g. parent and a child and a Hero(..) widget with the same tag.
When the user is on the "parent" screen and opens a "child" - the Hero widget is animated. When it goes back (via `Navigator.pop`) it's also animated.

I'm looking for a way to disable that animation when going back (from child to parent via `Navigator.pop`).

Is there a kind of handler which will be called on a widget before it's going to be "animated away" ? Then I probably could change `Hero` tag and problem solved.

Or, when creating a "builder" for a route in parent widget, I could probably remember a reference to a target widget and before calling `Navigator.pop` notify it about "you are gonna be animated out". That would also require making that widget stateful (I haven't found a way to force rebuild a stateless widget).

Is there an easier way of implementing this?

Answer (score 7):

While there currently isn’t a built-in way to disable Hero animations in any particular direction, though CLucera’s use of `FadeTransition` with `HeroFlightDirection` is one creative way, the most direct approach is to break the `tag` association between the two Hero’s:

When you go from the 2nd Hero back to the 1st Hero, just temporarily change the 1st Hero’s tag to something else, then the Hero won’t animate back. A simplified example:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String tag1, tag2;
  String sharedTag = 'test';
  String breakTag = 'notTest';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tag1 = sharedTag;
    tag2 = sharedTag;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Hero(
            tag: tag1,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("hi"),
              onPressed: () {
                // restore the tag
                if (tag1 != sharedTag) {
                  setState(() {
                    tag1 = sharedTag;
                  });
                }

                // second route
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return Scaffold(
                            appBar: AppBar(
                              title: Text(widget.title),
                            ),
                            body: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                child: Hero(
                                  tag: tag2,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    child: Text('hello'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      // change the tag to disable the reverse anim
                                      setState(() {
                                        tag1 = breakTag;
                                      });

                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                )
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                    )
                );
              },
            )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But if you want to directly modify the animation, then playing around inside the `flightShuttleBuilder` is the way to do it like CLucera did. You can also check out [medium/mastering-hero-animations-in-flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/mastering-hero-animations-in-flutter-bc07e1bea327) to further explore that area.

Answer (score 6):

The only approach that I can come up at the moment is to "Animate" the popping Hero in a way that seems not animated, let's check this code:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Hero(
          flightShuttleBuilder: (context, anim, direction, fromContext, toContext) {
            final Hero toHero = toContext.widget;
            if (direction == HeroFlightDirection.pop) {
              return FadeTransition(
                opacity: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(0),
                child: toHero.child,
              );
            } else {
              return toHero.child;
            }
          },
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text("prev 1"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          tag: "test",
        ));
  }
}
```

in your SecondRoute (the one that should pop) you have to supply a `flightShuttleBuilder` parameter to your `Hero` then you can check the direction and if it is popping, just hide the Widget with an `AlwaysStoppedAnimation` fade transition

the result is something like this:
[image]

I hope that this is something like the expected result, of course, you can completely change the transition inside the flightShuttleBuilder to change the effect! it's up to you :)